# How to call specific lines of a list for manipulation

Tags: python-3.x

This is a very basic example of my more complex code. I am trying to grab the first couple lines of the list and manipulate/store them in a new empty list. Same goes for the last two lines.

```
data = ['Temp =  45','Mass = 4', 'Color : Blue', 'Length : 17']
data2 = []
data3 = []


for lines in data[0:2]:
    for d in data:
            s = d.replace('Temp','Temperature')
            data2.insert(0,s)


for lines in data[2:]:
    for d in data:
        s = d.replace(':','=')
        data3.insert(0,s)

print(list(reversed(data2)))
```

The output I get returns all 4 lines of manipulated code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your inner loop

```
for d in data:
```

is what throws your code off. Did you mean the following?

```
for d in lines:
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running a for loop within a for loop, but you only want to iterate through the list once.

```
for d in data
```

is unnecessary in this case, and you can remove it and have the line under it be

```
s = lines.replace(':','=')
```

In this case, "lines" is each item in the list